# Signature verification of in-app billing v3 in PHP server with openssl_verify

Tags: php, android, openssl, in-app-billing

I have seen many posts with this issue and tested many possible solutions but the verification was always false.

So, I am passing both of this parametters via POST to the PHP server:

```
String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");<br>
String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
```

This is the method I use:

```
$result = openssl_verify($responseData, base64_decode($signature),
              key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
```

I used the method `json_decode` to verify that purchaseData is correct.
I also use `base64_decode` for the dataSignature.

And this is how I form my key with the public key that I have with my Google Publisher account:

```
const KEY_PREFIX = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n";<br>
const KEY_SUFFIX = '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

$key = self::KEY_PREFIX . chunk_split($publicKey, 64, "\n") . self::KEY_SUFFIX;
```

The tests are performed with an account test of a uploaded game in Google Play, so the In App Purchases are real but with no charges.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You have formatted the key but you are missing one step where you need to extract the public key from the PEM.

Here are the steps:

```
$key = self::KEY_PREFIX . chunk_split($publicKey, 64, "\n") . self::KEY_SUFFIX;
$key = openssl_get_publickey($key);
$result = openssl_verify($responseData, base64_decode($signature), $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
```